# obtain string between html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a userscript and I am trying to get the inner text of these bold tags. Unfortunately I can't use get getelementbyid or any of the getelement functions and because there are more bold tags that i dont need so I am trying regex. How would I go about getting the STRING123, STRING456, and so on?

I tried `(?<=bold\"\>)(.*?)(?=\<\/b\>)` but no luck
`bold\"\>(.*)\<\/b\>` gives me the entire stings but i want just the inner part.

```
<b style="color:#ffffff;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">STRING123</b>
<b style="color:#ffffff;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">STRING456</b>
<b style="color:#ffffff;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">STRING789</b>
<b style="color:#ffffff;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">STRING101112</b>
<b style="color:#ffffff;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">STRING131415</b>
```

Comment: what language are you using? why can't you use getElementById?

Comment: @Shimon Rachlenko javascript there is no id to call

Comment: Use `getElementsByTagName`, get the font-weight css of each, and see if it's set to `bold`. Then use `innerHTML` to get the text.

Comment: if you can use *jquery* the task is as simple as `$('b').text()`

Comment: @ShimonRachlenko Actually it would be `$('b[style$=bold]').text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine. The match will return the entire string, but you need only `$1` = first group of the particular match. 
So depending on programming language it's either `result("$1")` or `group(1)` etc.

**EDIT**

```
var myString = "style=color:#ffffff;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:10pt...";
var myRegexp = /bold\"\>(.*)\<\/b\>/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: sorry i'm using javascript

Comment: it works but returns bold">STRING<\b> how do i just get "STRING123" text

Comment: @Mr.1.0 `match[1]` returns `bold">STRING<\b>` for current regex??? Check exactly `match[1]`, not just `match`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it this way

```
/<b[^>]*bold[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/b>/g
```

Comment: He only wants the ones with `bold` in the style.

Comment: ah... ok, updated my answer, thought `<b>` was meant with "bold"

Comment: Maybe, but his original regexp looks specifically for "bold". It seems redundant to have this inside a `<b>` tag, but ours is not to reason why...

Comment: there are other `<b>` tags these specific `<b>` tags had a weight font of bold

Answer (score 0):

If the wanted `b` elements have their font-weight defined using inline styling, as in your example, you could use, for example

```
var i, b,
    bolds = document.getElementsByTagName('b');

for ( i = 0; i < bolds.length; i++ ) {
    b = bolds[i];  

    if ( b.style.fontWeight == 'bold' || b.style.fontWeight == '700' ) {
        console.log( b.innerText || b.textContent ); 
    }        
}
```